# Jackson: Deserialize map<String,Object> to Custom nested Pojo

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a simple `Map<String,String>` and I would like to deserialize it to a Pojo with some internal nested classes.

Example for map:
    Map = ["fname"="test", "lname"="test"]

Pojo code snippet:

```
class CustomPojo {
   private Username username;

   static class Username {
      private String fname;
      private String lname;

      @JsonCreator
      public Username(@JsonProperty("fname") String fname, 
                @JsonProperty("lname") String lname) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
   }
}
```

Calling code:

```
CustomPojo pojo = new ObjectMapper().convert(map, CustomPojo.class);
```

It fails, because it doesn't have any mapping for "Username" in the map.

Is there a nice way to solve this using annotations only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
private Username username;
```

Comment: New to me. Great ;)